# How to ensure JVM starts with value of Xms

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jvm, heap-memory

When I run a java program with the starting heap size of 3G (set by -Xms3072m VM argument), JVM doesn't start with that size. It start with 400m or so and then keeps on acquiring more memory as required.

This is a serious problem for me. I know JVM is going to need the said amount after some time. And when JVM increases is its memory as per the need, it slows down. During the time when JVM acquires more memory, considerable amount of time is spent in garbage collection. And I suppose memory acquisition is an expensive task.

How do I ensure that JVM actually respects the start heap size parameter?

**Update:** This application creates lots of objects, most of which die quickly. Some resulting objects are required to stay in memory (which get transferred out of young heap.) During this operation, all these objects need to be in memory. After the operation, I can see that all the objects in young heap are claimed successfully. So there are no memory leaks.

The same operation runs smoothly when the heap size reaches 3G. That clearly indicates the extra time required is spent in acquiring memory.

This Sun JDK 5.

Comment: Are you using Sun's JVM?

Comment: Just a question: How much main memory does your machine have and how much is free when you start your program?

Comment: The host has 32G memory. Though, 'top' shows only a few Gigs of free memory, the java program can comfortably allocate 10G.

Comment: The idea I had was, that you are close to swapping and when Java allocates another memory area, the OS has to take care of swapping and compacting.

Answer (score 3):

If I am not mistaken, Java tries to get the reservation for the memory from the OS. So if you ask for 3 GB as Xms, Java will ask the OS, if this is available but not start with all the memory right away... it might even reserve it (not allocate it). But these are details.

Normally, the JVM runs up to the Xms size before it starts serious old generation garbage collection. Young generation GC runs all the time. Normally GC is only noticeable when old gen GC is running and the VM is in between Xms and Xmx or, in case you set it to the same value, hit roughly Xmx.

If you need a lot of memory for short lived objects, increase that memory area by setting the young area to... let's say 1 GB **-XX:NewSize=1g** because it is costly to move the "trash" from the young "buckets" into the old gen. Because in case it has not turned into real trash yet, the JVM checks for garbage, does not find any, copies it between the survivor spaces, and finally moves into the old gen. So try to suppress the check for the garbage in the young gen, when you know that you do not have any and postpone this somehow...

Give it a try!

Answer (score 2):

I believe your problem is not coming from where you think.

It looks like what's costing you the most are the GC cycles, and not the allocation of heap size. If you are indeed creating and deleting lots of objects.

You should be focusing your effort on profiling, to find out exactly what is costing you so much, and work on refactoring that.

My hunch - object creation and deletion, and GC cycles.

In any case, `-Xms` should be setting minimum heap size  (**check this with your JVM** if it is not Sun). Double-check to see exactly why you think it's not the case.

Answer (score 0):

i have used sun's vm and started with minimum set to 14 gigs and it does start off with that.
maybe u should try setting both the xms and xmx values to the same amt, ie try this-
-Xms3072m -Xmx3072m

Answer (score 0):

Why do you think the heap allocation is not right? Taking any operating system tool that shows only 400m does not mean it isn't allocated.

I don't get really what you are after. Is the 400m and above already a problem or is your program supposed to need that much? If you really have the need to deal with that much memory and it seems you need a lot of objects than you can do several things:

If the memory consumption doesn't match your gut feeling it is the right amount than you probably are leaking memory. That would explain why it "slows down" over time. Maybe you missed to remove objects from one structure so they don't get garbage collected and are slowing lookups and such down.

Your memory settings are maybe the trouble in itself. Garbage collection is not run per se. It is only called if there is some threshold reached. If you give it a big heap setting and your operating system has plenty of memory the garbage collection runs not often.

The characteristics you mentioned would be a scenario where a lot of objects are created and shortly after they would be deleted again. Otherwise the garbage collection wouldn't be a problem (some sort of generational gc). That means you have only "young" objects. Consider using an object pool if you are needing objects only a short period of time. That would eliminate the garbage collection at all.

If you know there are good times in your code for running gc you can consider running it manually to be able to see if it changes anything. This is what you would need

```
  Runtime r = Runtime.getRuntime();
  r.gc();
```

This is just for debugging purposes. The gc is doing a great job most of the time so there shouldn't be the need to invoke the gc on your own.