# Java JVM parameter Xms doesn't take effect immediately

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jvm

I run my Java Application through tomcat, and set the -Xms1024m, however I found the size of the Java heap just 200~300m after start the application, I think the Xms means the minimum heap size, why the application doesn't reach to the minimum Heap size 1024m **immediately** after the application startup?

Edit, BTW, the JVM is hotspot 7.0.

It seems the GC does it in the 
method HeapRegion::setup_heap_region_size(uintx min_heap_size) from the c++ file        \openjdk-7-fcs-src-b147-27_jun_2011\openjdk\hotspot\src\share\vm\gc_implementation\g1\heapRegion.cpp  ,  and method   parse_each_vm_init_arg  from file  \openjdk-7-fcs-src-b147-     27_jun_2011\openjdk\hotspot\src\share\vm\runtime\arguments.cpp , someone who familiar with JVM GC source code can help to do some analysis for it.

[image]

Comment: I can't find documentation for this, but I would assume that simply because you allocate 1GB to the heap does not mean that this will be needed by your application.  If you app only needs 300mb, then this amount will be taken.  The [Oracle documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13150_01/jrockit_jvm/jrockit/jrdocs/refman/optionX.html) did not help to support this comment.

Comment: [How to ensure JVM starts with value of Xms](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/862176/how-to-ensure-jvm-starts-with-value-of-xms)

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Agree. I have tried this a few times in my applications and the initial allocated amount of memory was quite less than the value specified for -Xms (about 1/4 th of the value in -Xms). There was instances when it increased and occupied a greater share ( > 1/2) of -Xms value, if the initial contexts being set in the application were memory intensive.

Comment: I think maybe just the source code for the JVM can reveal the secret.

Comment: It seems the GC does it in the method HeapRegion::setup_heap_region_size(uintx min_heap_size) from the c++ file \openjdk-7-fcs-src-b147-27_jun_2011\openjdk\hotspot\src\share\vm\gc_implementation\g1\heapRegion.cpp  , someone who familiar with JVM GC source code can help to do some analysis for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It only shows you the space used. The heap size determines the capacity of each region. Note: the actual size available is less as you have two survivors spaces and only one is active in normal operation. e.g. say you have a survivor spaces of 50 MB each, a 1 GB heap will say only 950 MB is available.

When you set the minimum heap size, this doesn't mean that space has been used yet. However you might not get a GC until this heap size is reached (or when the Eden which is a portion of the heap is full)

Say you have a 1 GB heap and the Eden space is 100 MB to start with. You will get a GC once the Eden fills up even though little tenured space is used.  Eventually the Eden grows and the tenured space starts to fill and once it is full, it might grow the heap size to greater than the minimum heap size you gave it.

Comment: Thank you so much Peter.